# The program is error free but doesn't run fully and stops at a stage why?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char name[10]; int siblings;
    printf("enter the name\n");
    scanf("%s",name);

    if (strcmp(name,"larry")!=0) 
    {
        printf("you are not larry");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("you are larry\n");
        printf("how many siblings do you have\n");
        scanf("%d",siblings);
        fflush(stdin);
        printf("you have %d siblings Mr.%s\n",siblings,name);
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

/*This is the program running well till it prints "how many siblings do you have" and then stops working*/

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` invokes *undefined behavior*, so do not use it.

Comment: Because it's not error-free.

Comment: IKf the program is error-free, why do you ask?

Comment: Why are you not putting `&` for siblings? it is an integer right?

Comment: Next time you run it. and gets to the sibling part. Press '5' then enter. then tell us what kind of error you're getting. Also @JanLeeYu already gave you the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

The code `scanf("%s",name);` is okay because it is a string but, this one is not because it is not a string `scanf("%d",siblings);`. You will learn more about it when you reach [pointers](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_pointers.htm) and why you can just you can just remove the `&` sign for `char[]` or with arrays. That is a `runtime error` by the way. That is why you get the error while the program is already running.

Comment: hope it enlightens you. @Muthu Vivek

Comment: `scanf("%s",name);` is not really ok, it may overflow buffer and there is no way of preventing thos. suggest `scanf("%9s",name);`

Comment: okay. though it might just add confusion for beginners.